# ansible installing npm using nvm but returning npm command not found on npm install

Tags: npm, ansible, nvm

I am trying to install npm with nvm using ansible playbook script on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. It is getting installed but on running npm install command it returning an error `["/bin/bash: npm: command not found"]`

this is the script

```
- name: Create destination dir if it does not exist
    file:
      mode: 0775
      path: "/usr/local/nvm"
      state: directory
    when: "nvm_dir != ''"

  - name: Install NVM
    shell: "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | NVM_SOURCE="" NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm PROFILE=/root/.bashrc bash"
    args:
      warn: false
    register: nvm_result
```

This is the repository where I get the code (https://github.com/morgangraphics/ansible-role-nvm)

Answer (score 0):

By default shell module uses `/bin/sh` unless the executable has been explicitly defined in the module using args/keyword.

Seems like `/bin/bash`(a variation of shell is not is installed on the host) thereby giving error. Script needs bin/bash.

bin/bash is mostly installed on all the operating systems. May be some path issue.

Also updated the code below with condition.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create destination dir if it does not exist
      file:
        mode: 0775
        path: "/usr/local/nvm"
        state: directory
      when: "nvm_dir is not defined"

    - name: Install NVM
      shell: 'curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | NVM_SOURCE="" NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvmPROFILE=/root/.bashrc bash'
      args:
        warn: false
      register: nvm_result
```